# jQuery setting attributes with functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a simple function:

```
function addColoredBorder(color) {
    $(".coloredBorder").css({
        border-left: color,
        padding-left: "15px",
        border-radius: "10px"
    });
};
```

Then in HTML i would call the function, but for some reason, it doesn't accept it.
I know, you could do:

```
function f_border () {
  return "border:"
}

function f_attribute(x) {
  return x
}

function addColoredBorder() {
    $(".coloredBorder").css(f_border(), f_attribute());
});
```

But i need it to be as compact and simple for it to be as possible. toggleClass is out of question.

So experts, how can i set color without writing massive amounts of code?

(PS. The second block of code might not be correct at all, but i believe it goes somewhat like that.)

Comment: _"it doesn't accept it"_ please expand on this, in what way does it not accept it?

Comment: Your problem is that your css attributes are not in quotes. it should be "border-left": color, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript parser is not happy to have unquoted dashes in your object keys.

```
    "border-left": color,
    "padding-left": "15px",
    "border-radius": "10px"
```

or, jQuery supports camel-casing your CSS keys too:

```
    borderLeft: color,
    paddingLeft: "15px",
    borderRadius: "10px"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the colon from `border:` in the `f_border()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the property `border-left` to a color.  However, that is not the correct syntax for `border-left`.  It should be set to something like `1px solid #333`.  Therefore, if you want to write a function to change that do the following:

```
function addColoredBorder(color) {
    $(".coloredBorder").css({
        'border-left': '1px solid '+color,
        'padding-left': "15px",
        'border-radius': "10px"
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

object literal property names cannot have dashes in them unless they are quoted. So you need to use the camelCase version of the css properties or quote them

So code should look like:

```
function addColoredBorder(color) {
    $(".coloredBorder").css({
        "borderLeft": color,
        "paddingLeft": "15px",
        "borderRadius": "10px"
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors that causing issues.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addColoredBorder(color) {
                $(".coloredBorder").css({
                    'border-color': color,
                    'padding-left': "15px",
                    'border-radius': "10px"
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="coloredBorder" style="border:solid;">
This is a div content        
        </div>
        <button id="but1" onclick="addColoredBorder('red')"> apply red color </button>
    </body>
    </html>
```